# Lightbox library without a link

Tags: javascript, lightbox

Is there any lightbox library that allows me to insert any content (e.g. a div) without having  to click on a link?

I saw many libraries like [this one](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). A user is required to click on an image to see the lightbox. What I want instead is a timer that, after few seconds, makes a call to the lightbox to show up. The user can then close it if she wants to.

Comment: You could try simulating a click event on the image, thus triggering the lightbox... Not the most elegant solution, though.

Comment: I don't need to simulate anything. I can already have a time based trigger that shows a div with a fixed position few seconds after the page loads. However, I don't want to reinvent the wheel if some smart people have already done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jqueryui dialog, then call it open from code that you want:

```
function openLightBox(title,content){
    //append a div automatic
    if ('#divx').length <= 0) {
            $("body").append('<div id="divx" style="display:none; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto;" title="'+title+'"></div>');
        }
    //setup dialog
    $('#divx').dialog({
            zIndex: 300,
            width: 500,
            height: 400,
            resizable: false,       
            modal: true,       
            draggable: true,    
            buttons:{
                "close":function(){
                   $(this).dialog('close');
            }
           } ,
            close: function () {
                $(this).empty();
                $(this).dialog("destroy");
            }
        });
    //call it 
        $('#divx').dialog('open');
        $('#divx').html(content);
}

// you want to call it after page load 5 seconds?

$(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
     openLightBox('hello','<h1>my name is fox!</h1>');
     },5000);
});
```